# How to check if there is a defined value in the database - Discord.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, discord.js

How to check if I have a value defined in the database? If there is no value set, I want the bot to set a value.

I'm using `db.value() === null` and I'm setting all the values, but I think there's a better way to do this because when the bot sets the value in the database, the user has to run the command again , and my idea is: if the value doesn't exist, it will be defined in the database and the command will be executed normally.

My code:

```
database.ref(`Servidores/${message.guild.id}/Users/${message.author.id}/Economia`).once('value').then(async function(db){

    let dbref = database.ref(`Servidores/${message.guild.id}/Users/${message.author.id}/Economia`);

    if (db.val() === null) {
        dbref.update({
            id: message.author.id,
            money: 0,
            daily: 0
        })

        return message.channel.send(`${message.author} Acabamos de te registrar no banco de dados. Utilize o comando novamente.`)

    }

    if (db.val().daily !== null ) {
        //command
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Tarik Huber, you can use the [`DataSnapshot.exists()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#exists) method to check if data exists or not.

As for preventing the user from needing to run the command again, you could make clever use of `async`/`await` like so:

```js
// create a reference to the database location
const dbref = 
database.ref(`Servidores/${message.guild.id}/Users/${message.author.id}/Economia`);

// retrieve data from the reference
let db = await dbref.once('value');

// if the data doesn't exist
if (!db.exists()) {
  // update your data
  await dbref.update({
    id: message.author.id,
    money: 0,
    daily: 0
  });

  // update your `db` value to the new db value
  db = await dbref.once('value');
}

// this will either be the updated data (if there was no data before) 
// or the old data
if (db.val().daily !== null) {
  //command
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `exists()` check for the snapshot you get. You can call it like this:

```js
 if (snapshot.exists()){
      const data = snapshot.val();
      console.log("exists", data);
    }
```

Your code would look like this:

```js
database
  .ref(`Servidores/${message.guild.id}/Users/${message.author.id}/Economia`)
  .once("value")
  .then(async function (db) {
    let dbref = database.ref(
      `Servidores/${message.guild.id}/Users/${message.author.id}/Economia`
    );

    if (!db.exists()) {
      dbref.update({
        id: message.author.id,
        money: 0,
        daily: 0,
      });

      return message.channel.send(
        `${message.author} Acabamos de te registrar no banco de dados. Utilize o comando novamente.`
      );
    }

    if (db.exists() && db.val().daily !== null) {
      //command
    }
  });
```